# In iOS app, will receiving a silent push notification be counted as an active user in Flurry?

Tags: ios, flurry

I have set an Flurry event in the function below:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    [Flurry logEvent:@"ReceiveRemoteNotification"];
}
```

my question is whether the user will be counted as an active user by Flurry when we push a slient notification to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got reply from Flurry engineer, this will be counted as a session, but not a user.